# Clone div with new calculator for new divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some Jquery that I am using to clone a div, inside the div is an input that does a calculation.

When I clone the div and it creates a new div, the calculation does not work for the new divs. I understand that the calculation only works once the way I have it written. I have searched, but cannot find what I am looking for.

I also have an issue that when I add a number in the input the calculation works for the first div, but it also removes my buttons.

How can I have a new calculation for each new cloned div?
How can I stop the calculation from removing my add/remove buttons?

```js
function clone() {
  $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
    .appendTo("body")
    .attr("id", "clonedInput" + cloneIndex)
    .find("*")
    .each(function() {
      var id = this.id || "";
      var match = id.match(regex) || [];
      if (match.length == 3) {
        this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
      }
    })
    .on('click', 'button.clone', clone)
    .on('click', 'button.remove', remove);
  cloneIndex++;
}

function remove() {
  $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
}
$("button.clone").on("click", clone);

$("button.remove").on("click", remove);

// calculator
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".calculate").bind("keyup change", function(e) {
    var cabwidth = parseFloat($("#cabwidth").val()) || 0;
    var ply = 1.4375;
    var value = cabwidth - ply;

    if (!isNaN(value) && value !== Infinity) {
      $("#sum").text(value);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.clonedInput {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #def;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.clonedInput div {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
  <input type="text" class="calculate" id="cabwidth" placeholder="Cabinet Width">
  <div id="sum" />
  <div class="actions">
    <button class="clone">Add</button>
    <button class="remove">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bitlabs/0ah90uzr/)

Comment: Please note that cloning a node with an _id_ either results in _id loss_ or _invalid html_ (as an id should be document unique). Also, cloning a node does not clone any event listeners; these will need to be re-attached to the cloned node/s

Comment: so I should use class instead?

Comment: for valid html, yes. you should only have unique id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons get removed because their parent `<div>` has its contents overwritten (due to your invalid syntax). You're attempting to self-close your `sum` `<div>` with `<div id="sum" />`.

The **[`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)** element cannot be self-closed, as it is not a [**void element**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements); you must explicitly state that the element is empty with `<div id="sum"></div>`. Making this change fixes the problem with your buttons disappearing.

Note that you can validate your HTML markup with the **[W3C validation service](https://validator.w3.org/)**, to ensure that your HTML is valid (and thus behaves in a way that is expected). Also note that **[`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)** is deprecated as of jQuery 3.0; you should be using **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead.

As for your cloning not working, that is due to two reasons:

- The first being that you are cloning based on ID, and thus duplicating the ID. IDs must be **unique** throughout the DOM. Use classes instead of IDs, and use `$(this)` to refer to the specific cloned element.

  1. Change `#sum` to `.sum`, and instead of `$("#sum").text(value)`, use
     `$(this).parent().find(".sum").text(value)` to only affect the
     correct element.
  2. Change `var cabwidth =
     parseFloat($("#cabwidth").val()) || 0` to `var cabwidth =
     parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0`.
  3. Remove all use of IDs to ensure valid markup after the cloning.
- The second being that event handlers do not get attached to cloned elements. You need to hoist the scope to an element that is available on DOM load, and make use of [**event delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Instead of `$(".calculate").bind("keyup change", function(e)`, use `$("body").on("keyup change", ".calculate", function(e)`.

This is all fixed in the following example:

```js
function clone() {
  $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
    .appendTo("body")
    .find("*")
    .on('click', 'button.clone', clone)
    .on('click', 'button.remove', remove);
}

function remove() {
  $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
}
$("button.clone").on("click", clone);

$("button.remove").on("click", remove);

// calculator
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("keyup change", ".calculate", function(e) {
    var cabwidth = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    var ply = 1.4375;
    var value = cabwidth - ply;

    if (!isNaN(value) && value !== Infinity) {
      $(this).parent().find(".sum").text(value);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.clonedInput {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #def;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.clonedInput div {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="clonedInput">
  <input type="text" class="calculate" placeholder="Cabinet Width">
  <div class="sum"></div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button class="clone">Add</button>
    <button class="remove">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks. Do you know the second part of the question, how to have the calculation work in each one of the cloned divs? or should that be a different question form this post?

Comment: That is fine to include in the question, and I've updated my answer to cover **all** points that need to be changed to correct this behaviour :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an updated jsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/0ah90uzr/11/)

Some notes on what I changed:

- `.bind()` is depreciated
- Attached the change/keyup to the document, then passed `.calculate` as the selector, this will work with dynamic elements, whereas before it wasn't
- Made sure each clone and child elements have a unique ID
- Updated the calculate function to target elements relative to current input