# Jquery duplicate sum to other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that works, if I input a number for the "Cabinet Width" input, it outputs the sum in the div class="sum"

I also need it to duplicate that sum into div class="cal1" cal2 cal3, etc.

Is there a way to do that?

Here is the example: [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/0vbwn3bp/)

Code:

```js
function clone() {
  $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
    .appendTo("body")
    .find("*")
    .on('click', 'button.clone', clone)
    .on('click', 'button.remove', remove);
}

function remove() {
  $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
}
$("button.clone").on("click", clone);

$("button.remove").on("click", remove);

// calculator
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("keyup change", ".calculate", function(e) {
    var cabwidth = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    var ply = 1.4375;
    var value = cabwidth - ply;

    if (!isNaN(value) && value !== Infinity) {
      $(this).parent().find(".sum").text(value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clonedInput">
  <input type="text" class="calculate" placeholder="Cabinet Width">
  <div class="sum"></div>

  <div class="cal1">duplicate sum here</div>
  <div class="cal2">duplicate sum here</div>
  <div class="cal3">duplicate sum here</div>
  <div class="cal4">duplicate sum here</div>

  <div class="actions">
    <button class="clone">Add</button>
    <button class="remove">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to add `sum` class to the nodes you want to be affected by input:

```
<div class="sum cal1">duplicate sum here</div>
<div class="sum cal2">duplicate sum here</div>
<div class="sum cal3">duplicate sum here</div>
<div class="sum cal4">duplicate sum here</div>
```

So all of them would be in a game by

```
$(this).parent().find(".sum").text(value);
```

Comment: that is awesome! so simple I thought it would not work and never tried it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can chain multiple elements to output to at once inside of your `.find()`. Replacing `$(this).parent().find(".sum").text(value)` with
`$(this).parent().find(".sum, .cal1, .cal2, .cal3, .cal4").text(value)` will output the value to all five elements at the same time.

Alternatively, you could simply add the class `sum` to each of the desired target elements.

Hope this helps! :)

...also, this code looks [familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46697635/2341603) ;)

```js
function clone() {
  $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
    .appendTo("body")
    .find("*")
    .on('click', 'button.clone', clone)
    .on('click', 'button.remove', remove);
}

function remove() {
  $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
}
$("button.clone").on("click", clone);

$("button.remove").on("click", remove);

// calculator
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("keyup change", ".calculate", function(e) {
    var cabwidth = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    var ply = 1.4375;
    var value = cabwidth - ply;

    if (!isNaN(value) && value !== Infinity) {
      $(this).parent().find(".sum, .cal1, .cal2, .cal3, .cal4").text(value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clonedInput">
  <input type="text" class="calculate" placeholder="Cabinet Width">
  <div class="sum"></div>

  <div class="cal1">duplicate sum here</div>
  <div class="cal2">duplicate sum here</div>
  <div class="cal3">duplicate sum here</div>
  <div class="cal4">duplicate sum here</div>

  <div class="actions">
    <button class="clone">Add</button>
    <button class="remove">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Obsidian Age , I am still working on tweaking it with my data. @Obsidian Age wrote the example code that i used for this question.